# HTML meta viewport content working in chrome but being igored in firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, responsive, viewport

I have a web page that has this html meta tag
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>`

Whenever I make the browser responsive (select a mobile phone resolution), the change I make on this meta tag is reflected in chrome, but all the values are completely ignored in firefox regardless of the values are valid or not.

I have tried adding other attributes such as `minimum-scale`, `maximum-scale`,..etc. But no luck finding a workaround or a solution for this to reflect on Firefox.

Is there a reason that would make the browser ignore such tag or its attributes?

Comment: What version of Firefox? How are you "setting the resolution" in Firefox? How are you testing if the meta tag has any effect?

Comment: - Firefox version : 91.12.0esr (64-bit).  
- I'm setting the resolution by Inspect Element, then on the top right corner of the Inspect Element window I select the Responsive Design Mode. After that, I choose a specific mobile phone or I set the width x height resolution manually.  
- I'm testing if the meta tag has any effect as I make the changes in both chrome and firefox in the same time, and I see the change reflected in chrome and not in firefox

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Actually, after some searching. I found out that this is a configuration issue in Mozilla Firefox browser.
Setting 'dom.meta-viewport.enabled' this flag in about:config just solve the issue.
I'll post it as an answer.

Also, I'll be creating a new issue as it still occurs on apple devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Open Mozilla Firefox 
2- Go to **about:config** 
3- Search for **dom.meta-viewport.enabled** 
4- Change the flag value to **true** 
5- It should work now.